# All we knit is love meaning

Tags: meaning, metaphors

What does the following sentence means:
"all we knit is love"
Is it a famous metaphor?
Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like a play on words invented by a company supplying knitted woollen (UK) or woolen (US) things. That's all. You can imagine a bread company saying 'All we knead is love'. It is not anything significant.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Note: 'All You Need Is Love' is a very famous 1967 Beatles song.

Comment: Thank you ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a **pun**.

The famous quotation is "*all you need is love*", from the song of the same name by The Beatles. 'Knit' sounds a little bit like 'need', so it is a recognisable pun on this lyric.